# Using react-native-track-player To A Streaming Songs From Napster API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-track-player

I managed to build a simple music player using react-native-track-player following a tutorial as part of my learning curve in react native. Now, instead of just playing/streaming songs from provided url tracks in my array of songs, I want to stream the songs from API (though it can beb any API - but I have registered for Napster API) which I feel is not limited by just few songs. But, I can't put together how to implement or call the Napster API to fetch songs.
Please any help/guide I will appreciate so much.

Below is my code:

I have data.js, my array of songs:

```js
const songs = [
  {
    title: "death bed",
    artist: "Powfu",
    artwork: require("../assets/album-arts/death-bed.jpg"),
    url: "https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/death%20bed.mp3",
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    title: "bad liar",
    artist: "Imagine Dragons",
    artwork: require("../assets/album-arts/bad-liar.jpg"),
    url: "https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Bad%20Liar.mp3",
    id: "2",
  },
  {
    title: "faded",
    artist: "Alan Walker",
    artwork: require("../assets/album-arts/faded.jpg"),
    url: "https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Faded.mp3",
    id: "3",
  },
];

export default songs;
```

And here's my playerScreen.js :

```js
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import TrackPlayer, {
  Capability,
  useTrackPlayerEvents,
  usePlaybackState,
  TrackPlayerEvents,
  STATE_PLAYING,
  Event,
} from 'react-native-track-player';

import songs from './data';
import Controller from './Controller';
import SliderComp from './SliderComp';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

// const events = [
//   TrackPlayerEvents.PLAYBACK_STATE,
//   TrackPlayerEvents.PLAYBACK_ERROR
// ];

export default function PlayerScreen() {
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const slider = useRef(null);
  const isPlayerReady = useRef(false);
  const index = useRef(0);

  const [songIndex, setSongIndex] = useState(0);

  const isItFromUser = useRef(true);

  // for tranlating the album art
  const position = useRef(Animated.divide(scrollX, width)).current;
  const playbackState = usePlaybackState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // position.addListener(({ value }) => {
    //   console.log(value);
    // });

    scrollX.addListener(({value}) => {
      const val = Math.round(value / width);

      setSongIndex(val);
    });

    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
      // The player is ready to be used
      console.log('Player ready');
      // add the array of songs in the playlist
      await TrackPlayer.reset();
      await TrackPlayer.add(songs);
      TrackPlayer.play();
      isPlayerReady.current = true;

      await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
        stopWithApp: false,
        alwaysPauseOnInterruption: true,
        capabilities: [
          Capability.Play,
          Capability.Pause,
          Capability.SkipToNext,
          Capability.SkipToPrevious,
        ],
      });
      //add listener on track change
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.PlaybackTrackChanged, async (e) => {
        console.log('song ended', e);

        const trackId = (await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack()) - 1; //get the current id

        console.log('track id', trackId, 'index', index.current);

        if (trackId !== index.current) {
          setSongIndex(trackId);
          isItFromUser.current = false;

          if (trackId > index.current) {
            goNext();
          } else {
            goPrv();
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
            isItFromUser.current = true;
          }, 200);
        }

        // isPlayerReady.current = true;
      });

      //monitor intterupt when other apps start playing music
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemoteDuck, (e) => {
        // console.log(e);
        if (e.paused) {
          // if pause true we need to pause the music
          TrackPlayer.pause();
        } else {
          TrackPlayer.play();
        }
      });
    });

    return () => {
      scrollX.removeAllListeners();
      TrackPlayer.destroy();

      // exitPlayer();
    };
  }, []);

  // change the song when index changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlayerReady.current && isItFromUser.current) {
      TrackPlayer.skip(songs[songIndex].id)
        .then((_) => {
          console.log('changed track');
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('error in changing track ', e));
    }
    index.current = songIndex;
  }, [songIndex]);

  const exitPlayer = async () => {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.stop();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('exitPlayer', error);
    }
  };

  const goNext = async () => {
    slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (index.current + 1) * width,
    });

    await TrackPlayer.play();
  };
  const goPrv = async () => {
    slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (index.current - 1) * width,
    });

    await TrackPlayer.play();
  };

  const renderItem = ({index, item}) => {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: width,
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: Animated.multiply(
                Animated.add(position, -index),
                -100,
              ),
            },
          ],
        }}>
        <Animated.Image
          source={item.artwork}
          style={{width: 320, height: 320, borderRadius: 5}}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{height: 320}}>
        <Animated.FlatList
          ref={slider}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          data={songs}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: scrollX}}}],
            {useNativeDriver: true},
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{songs[songIndex].title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.artist}>{songs[songIndex].artist}</Text>
      </View>

      <SliderComp />

      <Controller onNext={goNext} onPrv={goPrv} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the `songs` into your current `PlayerScreen` through props.  You can use a separate component to load tracks from the Napster API and then render a `PlayerScreen` with those props.

The only part I'm not sure about is what path to pass to the player as the `url`.  The Napster data contains a property `previewURL` which is an `mp3` but it's not the whole song.  I believe that the `href` is the streamable URL.  It requires authentication to load the full track though.

The API path that I'm using here is for the most popular tracks.

```
export default function TopTracks() {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      try {
        const url = `http://api.napster.com/v2.2/tracks/top?apikey=${API_KEY}&limit=5`;
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setSongs(
          res.data.tracks.map((track) => ({
            duration: track.playbackSeconds,
            title: track.name,
            artist: track.artistName,
            album: track.albumName,
            id: track.id,
            url: track.href // or track.previewURL?
          }))
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    loadData();
  }, []);

  return <PlayerScreen songs={songs} />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I don't seem to understand what you mean by "I would pass the songs into your current PlayerScreen through props." because the file data.js that has the songs array still exist.